# Getting no response through jmeter but correct response through POSTMAN for same REST API

Tags: jmeter

I am new to REST API testing through JMeter.

Below are the steps I followed.

I retrieved the token from authenticate API.

Now I want to  retrieve the list of items. Token has been passed through header and parameters are passed through body of JMeter request.

After running the script , I receive the response code `200` and response as
`{ "success": true, "allact": [] }`

but no data between `[]`

If I perform same steps through Postman, second API gives correct response with same response code

Please help. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the requests differ for JMeter and Postman, I would recommend capturing them using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Once you identify the differences you will need to amend JMeter configuration to match what Postman sends. It might be something really minor, i.e. you forgot to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

---

In general given you're able to execute request in Postman you should be able to record the same request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is via [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File - Templates - Recording` and click Create
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click `Start`

     [image: JMeter Proxy]
2. Prepare Postman for recording in Postman preferences open `Proxy` tab and set both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols to use `localhost:8888`
   [image: Postman Proxy]
3. Execute your request in Postman
4. JMeter should capture the request under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) with all relevant headers, correct body, etc.

Comment: ...THanks for reply.I am not seeing PROXY option in settings page of postman..Is there any version issue.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri..it worked for me. Thanks for the help.